# Drop multiple tables at once

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In SQL you have the ability to drop multiple tables at once with a simple query like:
drop table a, b, c

In Snowflake this doesnt work. Is there a way to drop multiple tables at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can create a simple SP to do this for you:

```
create or replace procedure drop_tables(list varchar)
returns string
language javascript
as 
$$
    var l = LIST.split(',');
    var sqls = [];
    for (i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
        var sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + l[i].trim();
        var rs = snowflake.execute( {sqlText: sql});
        
        sqls.push(sql);
    }
    
    return JSON.stringify(sqls);
$$;

call drop_tables('mytest,test , my_table ');

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DROP_TABLES                                                                                 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| ["DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytest","DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test","DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table"] |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can do a 2 step like this where you generate the DDL if you have the list of tables to be deleted.

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name || ';' 
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE IN ('TAB1', 'TAB2');
```

Comment: im not quite sure what you mean. I do have a list of the tables that need to be deleted indeed. I have put the names of all the tables that need to be deleted in a table. But i dont see how i can integrate that with your query.

Comment: @Himanshu - saying to generate DDL's which holds drop statements from his query .. which will give DROP TABLE A1; DROP TABLE A2.... You can pull result  set  run it as -is which is technically same what you  are intending.